# does hibernate-redis supports 2nd level cache shared by different hibernate instances

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, redis

We want to use the hibernate-redis project
https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis
to support redis 2nd level cache.

Is this cache actually shared by different hibernate instances on different machines ? It should be so as redis is intended to be used that way, I have not confirmed that, but is anyone around there who used the redis cache to that effect.

For example, hibernate query from machine 2 does not hit the database and fetches the result from redis instead, because a previous query on machine 1 already fetched the same data and the data is stored in the redis cache.

Comment: I got a chance to try it. The redis cache is shared between different clients (they use the same redis for cache).

Answer (score 0):

Redisson hibernate module shares the same Redis database between multiple Redisson clients. In this case if application instace A and B connected to the same Redis and instance A already fetched data into cache through Redisson hibernate module then instance B get the same data from Redis.

It works for all types of Redis setup - cluster, single, sentinel, Azure Cache, AWS ElastiCache...