# Hibernate 2nd level Caching using redis for multiple containers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, redis, redisson

I have configured 2nd level cache for my spring-boot application using
`redisson-hibernate-53`. Here is the `redisson.yml` file for that,

```
singleServerConfig:
  address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

It seems to be working and required keys are being generated.
I have a couple of doubts about scaling:

1. If we deploy the application in multiple containers keeping the same redis db server config for each of them, will it work as expected or can there be issues ? I found stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490831/does-hibernate-redis-supports-2nd-level-cache-shared-by-different-hibernate-inst) related to this but could not find any answers. Also could not find anything in the docs.
2. If it works for multiple containers, what will be the performance impact ? Is it recommended to move to clustered redis config ?

Answer (score 1):

I got a chance to try the scenario. This is how I tested,

- Deployed the application on 2 different ports in my local computer.
- Checked for the keys generated and their last used `OBJECT IDLETIME key` and analysed the idletime after hitting from both the instances.

I found that the keys used by both the instances are the same and idle time is reset for the key by both the instances. So, I think it works fine when a single redis instance is shared across multiple instances.

About the performance impact, I guess the common disadvantages of single server instead of clustered servers apply (like performance and availability)

Comment: I gave an answer to this question here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57543969/764206

Comment: Thank you @NikitaKoksharov for the clarification.